# Reducing unnecessary joins in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-optimization

For simplicity sake let there be 2 entities in Symfony. The first one is called `Job` and the second one `Field` (category for `Job`). Each job can belong to multiple fields. `Job` is aware of it's fields, while the `Field` entity knows nothing about jobs.

```php
// Job.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Field")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="job_to_fields",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="field_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
private $fields;
```

When we want to load all jobs for fields `[1, 2, 3]`, I'd expect something like

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM job j
INNER JOIN job_to_fields jtf ON j.id = jtf.job_id
WHERE /* some other parameters */jtf.field_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

In reality Doctrine constructs this SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM job j
INNER JOIN job_to_fields jtf ON j.id = jtf.job_id
INNER JOIN field f ON f.id = jtf.field_id
WHERE /* some other parameters */f.id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

The second join (to the `field` table) seams unnecessary. Is there a way to remove this/tell doctrine not to do this?
In theory Doctrine should know about the relation of `f.id` and `jtf.field_id`, as it's using them in a join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct behavior because without that join calling `getFields()` on a Job object would not have access to the data to display.

You *might* be able to affect this by using lazy fetch on your $fields annotation, but if you ever call getFields() it will wind up running further queries to get the data anyway.

`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Field", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")`

But, unless you are addressing a specific issue, I'd let it ride. This is ORM doing what ORM does.